# In XPath 1.0, how can I test whether a string with length 1 falls between two others codepoint-wise?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

Given a document containing these tags, how can I tell whether " " < "H" < "z" in the document's encoding? I'm trying to do this in XPath 1.0.

```
<text>H</text>
<range>
  <from>&#x20;</from>
  <to>z</to>
</range>
```

I might even be able to get away with using contains(), but then how would I create a string containing the characters from " " through "z" to test against?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation finds if an ascii character is in the (inclusive) range of any two ascii characters**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vAscii"> !"#$%&amp;'()*+,-./0123456789:;&lt;=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:call-template name="isInRange">
    <xsl:with-param name="pChar" select="text"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pStarting" select="range/from"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pEnding" select="range/to"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="isInRange">
  <xsl:param name="pChar"/>
  <xsl:param name="pStarting"/>
  <xsl:param name="pEnding"/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
   "contains($vAscii, $pChar[1])

   and

    string-length(substring-before($vAscii, $pChar[1]))
   >=
    string-length(substring-before($vAscii, $pStarting))

   and

    string-length(substring-before($vAscii, $pEnding))
   >=
    string-length(substring-before($vAscii, $pChar[1]))

   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (that contains exactly the provided XML fragment):

```
<t>
    <text>H</text>
    <range>
        <from>&#x20;</from>
        <to>z</to>
    </range>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
true
```

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
    <text>H</text>
    <range>
        <from>A</from>
        <to>G</to>
    </range>
</t>
```

**again the correct result is produced**:

```
false
```

Comment: Hello Dimitre, 

That certainly does work, but does it scale to unicode? If I build a variable like:

<xsl:variable name="vUnicode">&#01x;&#02x;&#03x;...&#FFFFx;</xsl:variable>

will I run into any maxlen constraints?

Comment: @Telejester: There are no "maxlen constraints". Of course, this variable will take a lot of space... :) Seriously, I thought you needed this just for a fixed subrange of characters -- this solution is exactly for this case. Otherwise in XSLT 1.0 there isn't a suitable way of doing this. You may want to write an extension function that returns the code-point value (integer) for a given character.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible with XPath 1.0. It is with 2.0, though using the fn:compare function: http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/#compare

I'm not able to try it out but I guess the XPath would be:

```
fn:compare(text, range/from) > 0 and fn:compare(text, range/to) < 0
```